# Difference between "Writing English" and "English writing"

Tags: word-order, gerunds

Generally, what is difference between *noun + gerund* and *gerund + noun*? 
For example, *writing English* and *English writing*.

Comment: Those word combinations can be used in a few ways.  Can you please provide a sentence in which you could use either so it's more clear what you are asking?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a question about "Gerund". Generally, what is difference between "noun + gerund" and "gerund + noun" ?

Comment: When more details are requested, please use the [edit] button to include that information in the body of the post, not in the comments. Please note that we typically ask for details. If you do not [edit] your post, your question may be closed. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 2):

'Writing' can be used as both a noun and a verb.  'English' can be used as both a noun and an adjective.

'Writing English' is a verb-noun phrase which refers to the act of writing words in the English language

> I looked over Jackie's shoulder.  She was writing English, why couldn't I understand it?

'English writing' is an adjective-noun phrase which refers to written words that were written in English.

> English writing was engraved in the wall.

There are other, more unusual ways you could combine these words (for example, if you use 'English' as a noun referring to residents of England, you could use 'English writing' as a noun-verb phrase referring to a number of England's residents putting words on paper), but the two above are the most common.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very useful.